# IOS How can i get IDFA ? NOT import Adsupport.framework

Tags: ios

I want to get the IDFA, but I don't want to import Adsupport.framework, because this results in my app being refused on the App Store.

Can I get the IDFA without importing Adsupport.framework?

Comment: Why does linking against AdSupport.framework cause your app to be rejected? What's the reason given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into [OpenIDFA](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenIDFA). If you don't want to be rejected from the app store.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is **not possible**. I tried to access the `ASIdentifierManager` class without linking the framework, but it doesn't work this way.

```
NSClassFromString(@"ASIdentifierManager"); // Nil
```